# Why is there an iPhone in "All Eyez On Me"?

Tags: production, historical-accuracy, all-eyez-on-me

In the new 2pac movie, [All Eyez On Me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1666185/), there is a scene where Faith is taking a picture with 2pac and there is an iPhone.

This is chronologically impossible since the iPhone was released in 2007 and the movie was set from 1971 to 1996.

Why the director would allow such inaccuracy in a movie which is supposed to be a biography?

Comment: Money speaks louder than historical accuracy?

Comment: Who would watch more of your movies if you messed up in a legend's biography? So getting a bit of money one time is better than being known as the one who made a great piece?

Comment: @jNg Sadly, that logic does not hold.  People will keep coming back every time, no matter how terrible the previous movie was.  For proof, see Michael Bay's career.

Comment: @Paulie_D the movie came out in theaters 2 days ago, will be difficult to get an image unless someone leak and/or make it available on torrents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply just a [**movie mistake.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blooper). I thought they would have fixed it but since the movie was out 2 days ago (15/06/2017) they cannot fix it. Just sloppy filming in my opinion.

[image]

(above is the actual movie mistake)

It could however be sponsored by iPhone but I highly doubt it because according to [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/scottmendelson/2017/06/17/box-office-cars-3-races-to-19m-friday-all-eyez-on-me-snags-superb-13m/#2c18527b7583) the movie is projected to make 53m (USD) and has already made 13m in 2 days!

I cannot think of anymore explanations other than that but I have found a YouTube video that supports your claim :

50 cent posted this on his Instagram:

> When you look at this 2 PAC movie, and I know you want to say I'm
>   hating. But there's a scene in it where faith and PAC are taking a
>   picture and THEY HAVE A FUCKING IPHONE IN IT. what the fuck is this
>   man

He deleted the actual post but here is my source:
http://www.xxlmag.com/news/2017/06/50-cent-tupac-shakur-movie-all-eyez-on-me-trash/

I could not find any footage of the scene where she does it but I am going to take *50 cents* word for it and just say its a blooper.

He put another post up stating his opinion on the movie:

[image: See his Instagram post here]

Comment: What does matter how much the film box office is expected to be in relation to Apple sponsoring it?

Comment: They are already making that much money so they wouldn't want to risk making it historically inaccurate (thus making a bad movie) just for some extra money. If they weren't projected to make a big profit then sponsorship deals would have helped.

Comment: "Thank you Apple, we (think we will) have enough money, so we do not want any more" By your logic, no CEO would ever embezzle money!

Comment: Good point but to be fair if I was making a movie projected to make a massive profit I wouldn't bother making the movie inaccurate and subject to criticism just for some extra coins!

Comment: Well I doubt there will be a squeal so why not get as much as you can get,

Comment: I doubt they would put money over quality, it is what is a movie mistake. All movies have these little small mistakes but this was a massive mistake surprised they even made it considering the large amount of money they spent on it.

Comment: If that picture is legit **It isn't a mistake.** look at the picture on the phone: that's been edited onto the phone in post production. The image is too clear and the angle is wrong. You don't add an effect 'by accident'. I think that screenshot is probably bogus.

Comment: I am not sure if that even is the real picture but it appeared on social media so I assumed it is. It might be a different scene or the picture might just be fake

Comment: "but it appeared on social media so I assumed it is" - holy crap in a taxi cab, people...